# Finding difference between two dates using Joda in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, jodatime

I'm using Joda-Time and trying to find the difference between dates.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Here's my code :

```
LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate (19990-7-18);
LocalDate endDate = new LocalDate (2013-07-18);
Years Age = Years.yearsBetween(startDate, endDate);
int Age1 = Age.getYears();
String Age2 = new Integer(Age1).toString();
```

I'm using JOptionPane to view the result, and its telling I got 0 on (age1).

Comment: Please take the time to make sure that your code works and is properly indented before you post.

Comment: Seems like you defined your startDate in wrong format (19990-7-18). Change it to (1990-07-18)

Comment: Not sure if its because your start date year is wrong.

Comment: hello everyone @keppil @Korhan Öztürk @Bhushan. sorry for the wrong date. its 1990-07-18. i got it working now. thank you for the time answering. i just put `"`. now its working great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add quotation marks `"` to your LocalDate definitions to use the constructor that takes a `String` parameter:

```
LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate("1999-07-18");
LocalDate endDate = new LocalDate("2013-07-18");
```

What you have written evaluates to `long`s, and the two dates constructed will in fact be 0 years apart.

Comment: More precisely, they will be 17977 milliseconds apart.

Comment: hi @keppil thank you for your answer. i got it working now. i just put `"` now its tells the right age.